# Finding nearest unvisited exit by using a table of coordinates and cardinal exits in Lua

Tags: lua, maze

I am trying to code a lua script for a mud for which I have pgrogrammed a set of scripts. The mud recently has begun sending out room coordinates (, y and height) along with available exits (north east south).
I would like to code a script that will keep track of visited exits, and find the closest unvisited exit from the room I am currently in:
I tried consulting stackoverflow and many other sites on google but I found no answer so far, so I tried creating a table of coordinates which would keep track of the coordinates as strings of the coordinates put together by spaces and inside that keep a record of the exits leaving each room, then set up a table called backtrack which would keep track of all movements done by the character and coordinates it went to, so we could find the closest exit.
But this did not solve my problem, as sometimes the player moved into different locations and the loop I built to find the closest exits became stuck or didn't come up with any useful results.

Does anyone have any experience with this or has done something similar? I am clueless as to how I can handle this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The closest unvisited exit" means "the closest room with an unvisted exit".

With the room coordinates you can build a 2D map. Any (x,y) tile can be of one of three types:

type 2: visited and all exits visited (represented as #)

type 1: visited with unvisited exits (represented as X)

type 0: unvisited (represented as a space)

for instance:

```
  12345678
1
2 #X##
3    ###X
4      #
5     ##
6  X###
7    ###
8     X
```

Finding the nearest unvisited exit(s) is a simple breadth-first search problem starting from your position in this map. Let's say you represent a cell of your map like this:

```
{
  x = 2,
  y = 2,
  type = 1,
  exits = {
    east = cell_east,
    west = cell_west,
  }
}
```

You could write something like this to get the list of nearest rooms with at least one unvisited exit:

```
local visited = {}
local visit = function(to_visit)
  if #to_visit == 0 then return nil end
  local next,found = {},{}
  for i=1,#to_visit do visited[#visited+1] = to_visit[i] end
  for _,cell in ipairs(to_visit) do
    if cell.type == 1 then
      found[#found+1] = cell
    elseif cell.type == 2 then
      for _,exit in pairs(cell.exits) do
        if exit.type > 0 then next[#next+1] = exit end
      end
    else
      error("something went wrong")
    end
  end
  if #found > 0 then
    return found
  else
    return visit(next)
  end
end

my_list = visit({current_cell})
```

This is untested and not necessarily the most elegant or efficient way to solve the problem but it should give you an idea :)